# FullCalendar (angular) : is it possible to have a bar that shows where we are in the calendar (especially for the month view)?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFwoG.png) Something like in the image attached.
Or a progressive bar for events or another solution if you have one.
the now indicator is good for day and week view.

i have a problem  in my month view, i have an event that End on Monday 9AM and another that Start on Monday 9AM (the same Monday) because even if the first event end at 9am it appears like it finishes on Monday midnight in the  month view , So the users of my app make mistake between the two and they call the wrong person. I can't use the timeline month view because it's premium. is there any other way.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUBuk.png)

thanks.

Comment: It sounds like this is what you need: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/now-indicator

Comment: thanks ADyson, it resolve my problem for agendaDay and agendaWeek.

Comment: @ADyson is there way to have an indicator like that in le month view ?

Comment: @Drenai is it more clear now ?   am new here

Comment: @Cape_LeadWort the month view has no concept of time, only days. So it highlights the current day instead

Answer (score 1):

The "now" indicator is what you need

Documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/now-indicator

Set this option to true in your calendar options (e.g. in vanilla JS it would be `nowIndicator: true`) to show the indicator.

In time-aware views such as the timeGrid and timeLine this will show a thin marker line on the current time. In views which have no concept of time such as the month view, it will highlight the whole of the current day instead.